# Full-Size Hero-Background is not working

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, background, fullscreen

I would like to have a full size background, for my hero unit. I used the following code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="hero">
    <h1> hello world </h1>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.hero {
    background:url(../images/header1.png) no-repeat center center;
    background-size:cover;
    min-height:100%;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
 }
```

The problem with my solution: The background is only as high as my heading is. But the size should not depend on the content, it should depend on the viewers resolution.

Here is a perfect example: https://www.zirtual.com/ This hero-unit has also a fullscreen background-image. Thats the way, I would like to have it, too.

Comment: Add `height: 100%;` and `width: 100%;` to `html, body` as well and make sure `div.hero` is not in another element with an explicit height.

Comment: Thanks mate! That helped. Little explanation for better understanding, why i didnt work before?

Comment: Here's a little article that covers this topic: [How do you set the height of an element to 100%?](http://webdesign.about.com/od/csstutorials/f/set-css-height-100-percent.htm)

Answer (score 2):

You have to set a `100%` height for your `body` and `html` tag, and your `.hero` class.

Like this:

```js
body, html {
    height: 100%;
}

.hero {
    height: 100%;
    background: url("../images/header1.png") no-repeat center center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover; 
    -moz-background-size: cover; 
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/k728memz/)**

Answer (score 0):

make sure your html,body height and width is 100% .